# Restrict access to Member Preferences & Member Fields

Tags: members, control-panel

What is the best method to restrict a custom Member Group's access to Member Preferences and Member Fields?

I've created a Group that needs to be able to manage member data, but not have access to the other "settings" areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do kurt is use an addon like [Profile:edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) or [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor) and restrict member access to the channel you create which would hold member fields type data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually looking at Zoo Visitor at the moment for another project.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  The [**Can administrate members accounts**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#can-administrate-members-accounts) setting for a member group is all or nothing.